# How to get next li data value with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

```
<ul>
  <li class="x active" data-title="a"></li>
  <li class="x" data-title="b"></li>
  <li class="x" data-title="c"></li>
  <li class="x" data-title="d"></li>
</ul>

<button id="btn1">Click me to get next data-title</button>
```

if current active li has data-title of "a", how do i get the next li's data-title which is "b"?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    var next_data_title = $('li.active').next('li').attr('data-title');
    alert(next_data_title);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$("#btn1").on('click', function() {
    console.log($("li.active").next("li").attr('data-title'));
});
```

for getting the next li by the `.active` class. If you want to select the active item by its `data-title`, you can use

```
$("#btn1").on('click', function() {
    console.log($("li[data-title=a]").next("li").attr('data-title'));
});
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirtzbruch/zjm9rdya/1/) for a working example.